# Powershell-Passing in Parameters into a Function chain

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-1.0, powershell-3.0

Hello I am fairly new to Powershell and are trying to construct a series of functions that are governed by a parent function at the top level. 
This is the function that I am creating:

```
Function TraceIntegrityCheck{
    param($MasterTracefile, $FolderWhereATFare)
```

The `$MasterTraceFile` and `$FolderWhereATFare` will be file paths.  I will pass these in. Below is my script for all of the inner functions that will use the `$MasterTraceFile` and `$FolderWhereATFare` paths.

```
#-------------------------------MasterTraceConfiguration--------------------------
#*********************************************************************************
Function TraceIntegrityCheck{
param($MasterTracefile, $FolderWhereATFare)
[string](cat $MasterTracefile) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "\(in\)", ""} | Set-      Content 'C:\tempFile.txt'
$src = [IO.File]::ReadAllText('C:\tempFile.txt')
$pattern ='(?<Key>(APDU\s*:\s*80\s*E[68]))\s*(?<Num>(\b[0-9A-F]{2}\s+)+)'
[Regex]::Matches($src, $pattern) | % { [Regex]::Replace($_.Groups     ['Key'].Value, 'APDU\s:\s*', '') + ' ' + [Regex]::Replace($_.Groups ['Num'].Value, '\s+', ' ') }|set-content 'C:\tempFile.txt' 
$file1 = 'C:\tempFile.txt'
$file2 = 'C:\tempFileMod.txt'
$startValue = '^80 E6'
$innerValue = '^80 E8'
$regex4 = "(?m)\A(?=$startValue)|\r\n(?=$startValue)"
$regex5 = "(?m)$innerValue"
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($file1).TrimEnd()
$content -split $regex4 | Select-Object -Skip 1 |
  ForEach-Object -Begin {$i = 1} -Process {
    if ($_ -match $regex5) {
      $replacement = '{0:00}' -f $i++
      $file2 = $file2 -replace '\b(?=\.\w+$)', $replacement
      Set-Content -Path $file2 -Value $_ #-Verbose
    }
  }

#-------------------------------ATF Configuration---------------------------------
#*********************************************************************************

Function allOnOneLine{  
(([regex]::replace((get-content $FolderWhereATFare),"\s+"," "))).replace    ("9000","`r`n9000`r`n") > $FolderWhereATFare
}
#Call the Function
allOnOneLine

Function StripATF{
$original_file = '$FolderWhereATFare'
$destination_file =  'C:\modatfLinedup.txt'
(Get-Content $original_file) | Foreach-Object {
    $_ -replace '9000', '' 

    } | Set-Content $destination_file
}
#Call the StripATF
StripATF
#And the white space stripper
Function Wspace{
$file1 = 'C:\modatfLinedup.txt'
(gc $file1) | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | set-content $file1
}
#Call the Wspace
Wspace
Function spaceStrip{
$r=[regex]' ';
$original_file2 = 'C:\modatfLinedup.txt'
$destination_file2 ='C:\modatfLinedup.txt'
(Get-Content $original_file2) | Foreach-Object {
    $_ -replace '^ ', ''

     }| Set-Content $destination_file2
}
 #Call the Function
spaceStrip
Function folderDistribute{
  $file3 = 'C:\modatfLinedup.txt'
$file4 = 'C:\modATFLinedup.txt'
$startValue = '^80 E6'
$innerValue = '^80 E8'
$regex4 = "(?m)\A(?=$startValue)|\r\n(?=$startValue)"
$regex5 = "(?m)$innerValue"
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($file3).TrimEnd()
$content -split $regex4 | Select-Object -Skip 1 |
  ForEach-Object -Begin {$i = 1} -Process {
    if ($_ -match $regex5) {
      $replacement = '{0:00}' -f $i++
  $file4 = $file4 -replace '\b(?=\.\w+$)', $replacement
  Set-Content -Path $file4 -Value $_ #-Verbose
    }
   }
#Call the Function
folderDistribute
}
}
C:\Users\nicalder\Desktop\Project1\atf\atf\modatfs\modatf.txt
TraceIntegrityCheck -file1 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Project1\Master_Trace.txt' -    file2 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Project1\modatf.txt'
```

My problem lies in trying to string along the original $MasterTraceFile and $FolderWhereATFare files so that I can pass them into the function and have the child functions all use them.

So what I really want to do is just be able to pass in these two parameter file paths so that the child functions can use them. I guess essentially create a constructor that will allow me to use the passing in parameters.

I know this may appear as confusing so please let me know what you think. I am just trying to connect the files through the children functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you want to do something like:

```
function outer($a) {
    function inner($b){
        write-host -fore red $a
        write-host -fore red $b
    }

    inner 2

}

outer 1
```

The above does print:

```
1
2
```

That is, the `$a` from `outer` function is available in `inner` function

Comment: Yes thank you manojlds! This is what I was trying to do and I figured out that when I pass in a parameter I have to pass in with double quotes for a file path instead of a sigle quote like this: 

    TraceIntegrityCheck "C:\Users\nicalder\Desktop\Project1\MasterCard_Trace\MasterCard_Trace.txt" "C:\Users\nicalder\Desktop\Project1\atf\atf*.txt" 

Insead of this: 

    traceIntegrityCheck -file1 'C:\Users\nicalder\Desktop\Project1\MasterCard_Trace\MasterCard_Trace.txt' -file2 'C:\Users\nicalder\Desktop\Project1\atf\atf*.txt' Thanks so much for your help on this one! You rock!